# Media Foundation: H264 Encoder Dropping Frames

Tags: c++, video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to encode frame data from a monitor onto an MP4 file using `MFVideoFormat_H264` and a sink writer on Media Foundation using `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL`. I configured my input IMFMediaType to contain

```
inputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
inputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32);
inputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
MFSetAttributeRatio(inputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 60, 1);
MFSetAttributeRatio(inputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX, 120, 1);
FSetAttributeRatio(inputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN, 1, 1);
MFSetAttributeRatio(inputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
MFSetAttributeSize(inputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1920, 1080);
```

all on a 1080p monitor at 60Hz refresh rate. My outputMediaType is similar other than

```
outMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
outputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 10000000);
```

The sink writer itself is also configured such that MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING=TRUE and
MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS=TRUE to get the best possible performance out of it using hardware acceleration when available. Everything works and videos get created successfully. However, each video seems to have stutter across the entire duration. I've attempted lowering the bitrate and raising the average FPS to try and compensate but its more putting a bandaid on it. My assumption is that there are dropped frames causing this stutter as a result of a bucket overflowing?

Is anyone aware of a fix for this issue of frame drops/stuttering in the final video file while retaining the h264 encoding format?

EDIT: I've also tinkered with the different attributes on the input and output types setting
`hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIN/OUT, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN, 60, 1);` but to no avail.

Comment: In general, problems in the final h264 (here on MP4) are more the fact of what was  sent to it then media foundation itself or the encoder used. What is the final h264 encoder used? Try the sample and see if they are working well, for ex: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFCaptureToFile

Comment: @SimonMourier My use case isn't _too_ far off from the encoding portion of the sample you provided. My entire pipeline takes uncompressed RGB32 and finally making its way to the file with h264 baseline encoding. The only difference is that instead of reading from a video device, I am capturing frames directly from the monitor. I have also experimented, while keeping the attributes the same, with `MFVideoFormat_H264` coupled with `MFVideoFormat_HEVC` but videos still stutter in their final form.

Comment: Does the sample works well for you? If yes, then something's wrong with your code (no offense, we've all been there). I guess "Capturing frame directly from the monitor" can have influence on the rest of the workflow. There are many things that can be wrong, beside the output/sink. Difficult to say w/o more reproducing code. Also, how do you check the final result. For example, if you use tools such as VLC, you can sometime have a good H264 (not necessarily MP4) that is not visually nice because some read/connect settings are bad.